# Cloning queue in c#

Tags: c#, queue, clone

I have the following code:

```
Queue<string> oldQueue = new Queue<string>();

oldQueue.Enqueue("One");
oldQueue.Enqueue("Two");
oldQueue.Enqueue("Three");

Queue newQueue = oldQueue;
string newString = newQueue.Dequeue();
```

The problem is that once I Dequeue the item from `newQueue`, the item is also Dequeued from `oldQueue`.
Is there a way to "clone" a queue in a way that removing an item from one queue will keep it's clone queue unchanged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queue is a reference type, so newQueue and oldQueue holds a pointer to the same object. They are the same ;-)

See this answer about how to do a "deep cloning" using reflection:

[Deep Copy using Reflection in an Extension Method for Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198658/deep-copy-using-reflection-in-an-extension-method-for-silverlight)

Answer (score 25):

You have to make a deeper copy:

```
   //Queue newQueue = oldQueue;
   Queue<string> newQueue = new Queue<string>(oldQueue);
```

Comment: It will still hold a pointer to the same object in most cases so its not really a clone. You need to clone the objects it points to as well.

Comment: @rolls - for (immutable and internable) strings that would make no sense at all. For other data it would very much depend.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise the question was specifically about strings and thought it was asking generally .