# How to set value of queue to another queue?

Tags: c#, queue

How can I enqueue value of a queue (not it reference) to another queue?
It work like I have a queue of points in C++ (Queue<*word>), but I want to copy value of buffer queue like this

```
a = 1;
int[] array = new int[1]
array[0] = a //array[0] now is 1
a = 0 // but array[0] doesn't change, array[0] is 1!
```

I have problem in words.Enqueue(buffer)

```
using word = System.Collections.Generic.Queue<char>;

Queue<word> words = new Queue<word>();  //word is the custom type, that was def in file top
word buffer = new word();

for (var symbol_count = 0; symbol_count < text.Length; ++symbol_count)
{

    if (text[symbol_count] != ' ' && text[symbol_count] != '.' && text[symbol_count] != ',')
    {
        buffer.Enqueue(text[symbol_count]); //store one char in word
    } 
    else 
    {
        buffer.Enqueue(text[symbol_count]); //store end of word symbol
        words.Enqueue(buffer);  //store one word in words queue, but compiler do it like I try to copy a reference of buffer, not it value!!!
        //System.Console.WriteLine(words.Count); DEBUG
        buffer.Clear(); //clear buffer and when i do this, value in words queue is deleted too!!!
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I have problem in words.Enqueue(buffer)"*. So what is the problem?

Comment: I insert in "words" queue not a value of "buffer" queue, but it's pointer. And when I change a value of "buffer" queue, it also change in "words" queue. But I want just copy a value of "buffer" queue in "words" queue

Comment: It's a little confusing to read when you alias `Queue<char>`

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209747/cloning-queue-in-c-sharp. Or just create a new queue instead of `Clear`ing the old one.

Comment: @Rufus L, sorry for this, I thought that this trick improve readability of code :C

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question fully, but it sounds like you want to make a deep copy of a value in your queue and enqueue it in a different queue? Here's a link that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net-c-specifically

Comment: Yes, "deep copy" that's what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're re-using the same `buffer` in your loop, so when you clear it, all the references to it are also cleared.

Instead, set the local `buffer` variable to a *new* instance of the object, so that any changes to it don't affect the reference we just stored:

```
foreach (char chr in text)
{
    buffer.Enqueue(chr);

    if (chr == ' ' || chr == '.' || chr == ',')
    {                     
        words.Enqueue(buffer);

        // reassign our local variable so we don't affect the others
        buffer = new Queue<char>();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

When you save a new word to a queue (you might have a bug with the last word here, by the way)

```
words.Enqueue(buffer);
```

You shouldn't use the `buffer` variable itself: it holds a reference to the temporary data and you need to make a copy of it first, something that will not be modified in the next lines.

Try e.g.

```
words.Enqueue(new word(buffer));
```

Comment: Thank you for help!

Comment: @MagicianArtemka you are welcome. Note though, that I was answering your question here, basically _how to use queue value and "detach" it from queue reference_. For the underlying problem, however, the code by Rufus is more straightforward and efficient.