# How to make a copy of an instance?

Tags: c#

In this following code, what I want to do is to add a new value to my queue and then calculate the average of my current queue. But I don't want to just perform the calculation directly on my current queue itself. Instead I want to first copy the content of the current queue to a new queue and perform the calculation on the new queue. But I know that since classes are reference variables, so if I perform change anything within the new queue, the original one will change along. So how do I make a copy of the original queue and make changes on it without changing the original one?

```
public class MovingAverage {


public int size;
public Queue<int> que = new Queue<int>();
public Queue<int> copy = new Queue<int>();

/** Initialize your data structure here. */
public MovingAverage(int size) 
{
    this.size = size;
}


public double Next(int val) 
{
    if (que.Count == size) que.Dequeue();
    que.Enqueue(val);   
    
    copy = que;
    
    double sum = 0;
    while(copy.Count != 0){
        sum = sum + copy.Dequeue();
    }
    return sum / que.Count;      
}
```

}

Comment: That's what's called a deep copy. You have to create a new instance and copy the values from the source to the target object. Custom type properties should follow the same rule if they are reference types.

Comment: Instead of messing with copying you can store a current sum of your queue. At first it's 0, if you add new elements, you add the value to the sum, if you dequeue, you subtract the value. The average value is then simply `sum/size`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cloning queue in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209747/cloning-queue-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

To make a copy of a Queue you can pass an enumerable collection to the constructor of a new instance

```
var newQueue = new Queue<int>(existingQueue);
```

As your Queue contents are ints (not reference types) they will not be connected to the original elements but beware, if you did this with a Queue full of class of eg Person, that each Queue instance would reference the same Persons and changing eg the Name property of the head Person would mean that each Queue sees the change

```
var q1 = new Queue<Person>( new [] { new Person() { Name = "Joe" } } );
var q2 = new Queue<Person>(q1);
q1.Peek().Name = "Jane";
Console.WriteLine(q2.Peek().Name); //prints Jane


//in essence, in memory, you have this:

q1 --head--> Person{ Name = "Joe" }
q2 --head----^

Two queue instances, but both of them have a reference to the same Person;
If you alter something about the Person, such as their Name, both Queues see it
```

You are free to change something about the Queue itself, as they are different instances:

```
var q1 = new Queue<Person>( new[] { new Person() { Name = "Joe" }, new Person() { Name = "Jane" } } );
var q2 = new Queue<Person>(q1);    //both queues have two people in
Console.WriteLine(q1.Peek().Name); //Joe
Console.WriteLine(q2.Peek().Name); //Also Joe

q1.Dequeue(); //bye bye Joe
Console.WriteLine(q1.Peek().Name); //Jane
Console.WriteLine(q2.Peek().Name); //Joe
```

But the different queues point to the same Persons so you cannot mutate the Person objects independently. To do that, you'll have to clone/make anew the Person objects too, perhaps like:

```
var q2 = new Queue<Person>(q1.Select(p => new Person { Name = p.Name }));
```

Comment: Yes it worked. I just replaced "copy = que;" with "var copy = new Queue<int>(que);".