# How can I write the code to get all the properties of a class?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program, where I want to create a new instance of the object depending on a value, I take the value and then search the list and using that list I create a new instance.

Well, it goes perfectly well. But there is a problem, that I have to write them all manually and it takes a long time. I wanted to know whether there is a better way of doing this or not, here is the C# code I am having

```
public Account (int userId) {
    // here is look for the account
    // inside a List<Account> which returns the account
    // then I update the values for that instance, 
    this.AccountLockedSince = account.AccountLockedSince;
    this.AuthenticationToken = account.AuthenticationToken;
    this.CreateDate = account.CreateDate;
    this.IsLocked = account.IsLocked;
    this.IsVerified = account.IsVerified;
    this.PasswordResetDate = account.PasswordResetDate;
    this.PasswordResetToken = account.PasswordResetToken;
    this.RequireEmailVerification = account.RequireEmailVerification;
    this.TokenExpires = account.TokenExpires;
    this.UserId = account.UserId;
}
```

.. as you can see, these are all the properties of the Account class and I have updated them, but this is not the efficient way of doing this. Any built-in feature in the C# .NET framework to handle this?

Comment: Sir what is the benefits of writing articles on C# Corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> The MemberwiseClone method creates a shallow copy by creating a new object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to the new object. If a field is a value type, a bit-by-bit copy of the field is performed. If a field is a reference type, the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object and its clone refer to the same object.

If you need a deep copy, rather than a shallow copy, try [using serialization to create a deep copy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23832/Implementing-Deep-Cloning-via-Serializing-objects).

You can also get and set properties using Reflection.  See [Deep Copy using Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198658).

Comment: I will get down into it. :-)

Answer (score 2):

MemberwiseClone is fine, but I would sugget installing the AutoMapper nugget package and start using it! It is really versatile and I use it a lot at work.

The idea is that if you want to copy the properties of an object you do

```
    var shallowCopy = Mapper.DynamicMap<Account>(account);
```

The good thing is that you can define mappings between types beforehand, like this:

    `Mapper.CreateMap<TypeA, TypeB>()
          .ForMember(b => b.Tutu, opt => opt.MapFrom(a => a.Toto.Titi));`
This way, when you will map from a TypeA to a TypeB, the propery Tutu of TypeB will be filled by the property Titi of Toto in TypeA. These mappings have lots of options to handle all the cases you may wish to handle ;)

Answer (score 1):

I see you want to automate updating of the properties of your class - for which the answers given above might be fine. But if you simply want to get the names of all the properties of the class the following is the simplest way, I guess.

```
 IEnumerable<string> properties = typeof(Account).GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name);
```

Comment: This one is a great thing to do!