# Proper way of copying values between lists in C#?

Tags: c#

Lets say we have a list of Employee (`List<Employee> EmployeeList`) , where each employee has Name (string).
If we were going to have a new list of just employee names is doing the following correct/best practice?

```
List<string> NameList = new List<string>();
foreach( Employee e in EmployeeList)
{
  NameList.Add(e.Name);
}
```

What if instead of string we were dealing with Complex type e.g. copying the list of employees from one list to another e.g.:

```
List<Employee> newEmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
foreach( Employee e in EmployeeList)
{
  if (Employee.YearsWorked<2)
  newEmployeeList.Add(e);
}
```

newEmployeeList would not have a separate copy of Employee instances to EmployeeList. Is that correct? If yes then how do we create separate copies efficiently (in code)?

Comment: Your question is lagging the correct explanation of the Problem, What is the type of EmployeeList is it a class or List<ListItem>

Comment: Thank you @SaiKalyanKumarAkshinthala, it is List<Employee>. Updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a new object of the `Employee`, you should implement the `ICloneable` interface on your `Employee` class. You can then use either:

```
List<Employee> newEmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
foreach( Employee e in EmployeeList)
{
   if (e.YearsWorked<2)
   newEmployeeList.Add(e.Clone());
}
```

or:

```
var newEmployeeList = (from e in EmployeeList where e.YearsWorked < 2 select e.Clone()).ToList();
```

Comment: No need to implement `ICloneable`, especially because its `Clone` method returns `object`. Just implement a `Clone` method that returns `Employee`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use Linq to project the new collection (include `using System.Linq;` if you haven't done so already):

```
var newEmployeeList = EmployeeList
            .Where(e => e.YearsWorked < 2)
            .ToList()
```

Just like your manual `new List<> / Add`, this just creates a new list, but to the same `Employee` references as in the original `EmployeeList`. If you want a deep copy of the contained entity, you will generally use a [technique like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198658/deep-copy-using-reflection-in-an-extension-method-for-silverlight) a serialization / deserialization cycle, or using reflection, recursively if you have a deep graph under `Employee`.

Comment: Thank you Stuart, I was after getting a new copy.